# How to get next job to process after previous has finished in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I know node.js works mostly asynchronous, but what if I want to process a job after the previous job has finished.
What I want is, I want to loop in a queue and get next job to process. If the job has processed, I get the next. The problem is, because the process is asynchronous, next job is fetched before the previous job has finished.

```js
    jobs.ForEach( async job => {
      await process(job);
    });
```

So, how can make it such, that the next iteration is done after process(job) has finished. Ironically, I want to make the for-loop synchronously.
I could solve it by using EventEmitter and send an finish-event in the process() implementation, to notify the process is done. But is there a cleaner way to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: You can use for .. of instead of foreach

Comment: Guys, put one of your suggestions as an answer so I can accept it.